# to get key /values of a list matching the dictionary

Tags: python, nlp

A training data(data_tr->consists of 11300 doc encoded in numeric values given below as array for each documents). The vocabulary is a dictionay consisting of keys and values of 2000 most frequent words. My problem is to convert the array of data_tr(numeric) to words using dictionary (key,values ) pairs for the whole training data(data_tr). I am new to python programming.

```
data_tr= [array([ 700,  152,  572,  572,  619,  724,  326, 1571,  572,   99,  724,
        326, 1571,  276,    1,  281, 1232,  267,  267,  222,   11,    2,.......dtype=int64)
 array([ 331,  152,  397, ..., 1273,   89,  228], dtype=int64)...............

vocab = {'limited': 1481, 'child': 181, 'four': 586, 'sleep': 1714, 'hate': 1141, 'forget': 607, 'whose': 902, 'violate': 1945, 'bike': 370, 'swap': 1616, 'lord': 889, 'sorry': 480, 'worth': 625, 'risk': 911, 'rise': 1474, 'every': 119,...........}
```

**I tried to solved the problem as :**

```
    keys=list(vocab.keys())
    values=list(vocab.values())
    for e in data_tr[0]:
         print (keys[values.index(e)])
```

Here it works fine for one document(data_tr[0]) but fail to produce words (data_tr)for the whole training data(data_tr).I wanted to get back the words for all the documents(11300 doc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I think that it will be easiest if you construct a reversed dictionary so that you can look up from the numbers to the words:

```
vocab_r = dict((v, k) for k, v in vocab.items())
```

Based on further discussion, it seems that you probably want something like:

```
for doc in data_tr:
    print([vocab_r[e] for e in doc])
```

or maybe a list of lists:

```
print([[vocab_r[e] for e in doc] for doc in data_tr])
```

Comment: Hi Alaniwi, Thank you so much for the help. The data type for data_tr is 'numpy.ndarray'. The code works but it returns the whole collection of all words in data_tr. I was looking to get back in list of list for all the documents. Ex:  [ [doc1 (words )][doc2 (words)]......]

Comment: @Amit Okay I have updated my answer accordingly.  I hope this is applicable now.  The more exactly you describe the required output in the question, the more chance that any answers will meet that requirement.